# XPath - Nested path scraping

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to perform html scrapping of a webpage. I like to fetch the three alternate text (alt - highlighted) from the three "img" elements.

I'm using the following code extract the whole "img" element of slide-1.

```
          from lxml import html                    
          import requests
          page = requests.get('sample.html')
          tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
          text_val = tree.xpath('//a[class="cover-wrapper"][id = "slide-1"]/text()')
          print text_val
```

I'm not getting the alternate text values displayed. But it is an empty list.

HTML Script used:

[image: Sample html script]

Comment: Don't you want `[class="showcase-wrapper"]`?

Comment: Please include the code with `code formatting` instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//a[@class="cover-wrapper"]/img/@alt
```

So, I am first selecting the node having a tag and class as cover-wrapper and then I select the node img and then the attribute alt of img.

To find the whole image element :

```
//a[@class="cover-wrapper"]
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is one possible XPath :**

```
//div[@id='slide-1']/a[@class='cover-wrapper']/img/@alt
```

**Explanation :**

- **`//div[@id='slide-1']`** : This part find the target `<div>` element by comparing the `id` attribute value. Notice the use **`@attribute_name`** syntax to reference attribute in XPath. Missing the `@` symbol would change the XPath selector meaning to be referencing a -child- element with the same name, instead of an attribute.
- **`/a[@class='cover-wrapper']`** : from each `<div>` element found by the previous bit of the XPath, find child element `<a>` that has `class` attribute value equals `'cover-wrapper'`
- **`/img/@alt`** : then from each of such `<a>` elements, find child element `<img>` and return its `alt` attribute

You might want to change the `id` filter to be `starts-with(@id,'slide-')` if you meant to return the all 3 `alt` attributes in the screenshot.

Comment: I'm missing something here...I'm getting an empty list as output. I'll do some analysis on my side ... thanks for the detailed explanation. I appreciate it ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
//div[@class="showcase-wrapper"][@id="slide-1"]/a/img/@alt
```